# Internationalization of strings with html tags and numbers in WordPress

Tags: localization

How to translate a string with tags in between.

Suppose there is a string like

```
$a = 5;
There are <?php echo $a; ?> <span>people</span> in this country.
```

Javascript files:

```
wp_localize_script( 'store-locator', 'storelocatorjstext', array(
    'nostores'   => __( 'There are 5 people in this country.', 'textdomain' )
) );
```

What is the correct way of internationalizing such cases?

My approach:

```
<?php _e('There are 5 <span>people</span> in this country.', 'textdomain'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the translation in a [printf](http://php.net/printf) function. [printf](http://php.net/printf) ( or [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) for when you don't want to print to the screen immediately ) allow you to put placeholders in the string. See the documentation for all the type specifiers

Use __() instead of _e() because printf already outputs to the screen.

```
$no_people = 5;

printf( __( 'There are %d <span>people</span> in this country.', 'textdomain' ), $no_people );
```

---

**Edit**

Added example for wp_localize_script

$no_people = 5;

```
$nostores = sprintf( __( 'There are %d <span>people</span> in this country.', 'textdomain' ), $no_people );

wp_localize_script( 'store-locator', 'storelocatorjstext', array(
    'nostores'   => $nostores
) );
```

Comment: Thanks. In PHP you can mention dynamic variable with %d. But how to do so in Javascript? Please check the updated question for JS code

Comment: Do the exact same thing but use sprintf. You can then save the entire translated string in a variabe and send that to the javascript localization.

See updated answer

Comment: Yes But I meant a dynamic JS variable. Since this was off topic for my current question. I created a new question. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255514/internationalization-of-strings-with-javascript-dynamic-variable